# Can the Apache <Location> directive be safely used to configure access to a server?

Tags: apache2, basic-authentication, http-authentication, digest-authentication

In my Apache configuration, I first deny access to the entire filesystem:

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Then, in the configuration for each virtual host, I allow unrestricted access:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or require authenticated access:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "example.com"
        AuthUserFile htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I noticed in the Apache documentation that:

> [For content that lives in the filesystem, use <Directory> and <Files>. An exception is <Location />, which is an easy way to apply a configuration to the entire server.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location)

And I wondered whether using `<Location />` might be a way to require authenticated access for a particular virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "example.com"
        AuthUserFile htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But the Apache documentation states that:

> [<Location> directives should not be used to control access to filesystem locations.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location)

Which led me to wonder whether *should not* was a recommendation for `<Location>` directives in general, and whether in certain situations a `<Location />` directive in particular may be used as *an exception* to allow access, or in other words, can the Apache `<Location>` directive be safely used to configure access to a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**  Also from the Apache documentation:

> [Pay particular attention to the interactions of Location and Directory directives; for instance, even if <Directory /> denies access, a <Location /> directive might overturn it.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles)

My understanding is that because any `<Location>` directive could potentially overturn any `<Directory>` directive[1], the least restrictive `<Location>` directive must not be less restrictive than the most restrictive `<Directory>` directive **across the entire server**.

Starting with a sensible `<Directory />` default of `Require all denied` and following the above rule would require any `<Location>` directive to not be less restrictive than `Require all denied`, which would of course make it impossible to access the server at all.

Note also that the purpose of the `<Location>` directive is to configure resources which reside outside of the filesystem.

**Bottom line is that for any requests which might touch the filesystem, for any `<Location>` directives which might apply to any of those requests, the applicable `<Location>` directives must not include the `Require` statement.[2]**

[1]: For example, using symbolic links.
[2]: It is possible to use filesystem permissions or tools like apparmor to mitigate the security hole opened by including a `Require` statement in certain `<Location>` directives, but remember the principle of [Defense In Depth](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Defense_in_depth).